# O que seria um "tuga de gema"?

Tags: expressões, português-europeu

Aqui pelo Portuguese SE e pelo chat percebi que os portugueses têm o costume de se chamarem de "tuga de gema".

Pesquisei sobre "tuga" e descobri que é a abreviação de "portuga", mas por que "de gema"? Seria equivalente a ser um português "roxo"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Como podes ver no ponto 6 da definição de gema, ***figurado*** aquilo que é mais puro, mais genuíno, ou seja, um **tuga de gema** é uma português com descendência unicamente Portuguesa.

É comummente usado em expressões como:

> *Eu sou um tuga de gema, como feijoada todas as semanas.*
>
> *Estas a comer [sopa de cavalo cansado](http://www.papodevinho.com/2008/09/sopa-do-cavalo-cansado.html) ao pequeno almoço, és um tuga de gema.*

Nestes casos tenta demonstrar o quão Português uma pessoa é. Não que se possa medir, mas para dar ênfase ao ser-se Português e seguidor dos costumes.

> ### [ge.ma](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/gema) [ˈʒemɐ]
>
> 1. óvulo ou ovo com grande quantidade de reservas nutritivas, como o dos répteis e das aves
> 2. parte globosa, amarela, central, do conjunto que vulgarmente se considera ovo (de ave ou de réptil)
> 3. **BOTÂNICA** formação vegetal, em regra ovoide ou subglobosa, que, pelo seu desenvolvimento, origina um ramo, gomo, borbulha, renovo, rebento
> 4. **MINERALOGIA** qualquer pedra preciosa ou semipreciosa
> 5. **figurado** centro, âmago
> 6. **figurado** aquilo que é mais puro, mais genuíno

Comment: Sopas de cavalo cansado! Ouvi falar disso. Ainda se come no teu Portugal? :)

Comment: @Jacinto Sim claro que se come, os mais velhos ainda fazem de manhã. O pessoal mais novo come, mas só para experimentar.

Comment: Tenho que experimentar, ou ainda põem em causa o meu estatuto de gema.

Comment: Jacinto quase fazias um trocadilho porque a sopa realmente pode levar gemas ;)

Comment: Jorge, "português com descendência unicamente Portuguesa."   não seria [**ascendência**](http://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/gramatica/ascendencia-descendencia.htm)?

Comment: Por outro lado, minha mãe é portuguesa com ascendência unicamente portuguesa mas veio para o Brasil com dois anos de idade.  Não creio que ela seja uma "tuga de gema".

Comment: Jorge, acho que a resposta ficava ainda mais sólida se incluísses um exemplo de uso de "de gema" que não fosse "**português** de gema".

Answer (score 6):

Eu acuso-me: usei essa expressão há poucos dias no chat do Portuguese SE. Um *português de gema* é nascido e criado em Portugal; português desde a sua origem. A *gema* é o núcleo do ovo ou do óvulo, a partir do qual se desenvolve o novo ser. Naturalmente também se pode dizer *brasileiro de gema, francês de gema, gaúcho de gema*, etc. E como podem ver na resposta do Centaurus, os cariocas também usam esta expressão.

E para pôr a expressão em contexto, um outro português gracejava acerca da expressão *tem uma regra* numa proposta de edição de um post (em Portugal só se diz *há/existe uma regra*) e eu disse-lhe

> Até fui eu, tuga de gema, quem sugeriu o uso de *tem uma regra*.

Parece que já estamos esclarecidos que [*português roxo*](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/o-que-%C3%A9-um-portugu%C3%AAs-roxo) não significa *português de gema*, embora eu chegasse a imaginar que significavam a mesma coisa, influenciado pela sugestão do OP e por me lembrar de um político brasileiro que ficou célebre por ter dito que tinha nascido com aquilo roxo. O argumento é algo subtil e está explanado nos comentários abaixo.

Comment: "Roxo" seria sinônimo de "fervoroso", como em "corintiano roxo", "católico roxo", etc. Mas pelas definições que foram dadas, pelo visto não é a mesma coisa. :)

Comment: Ah, fica roxo de fervor. Não é a mesma coisa mas estão relacionados. Uma pessoa quando diz ser _qualquer coisa de gema_, não quer normalmente indicar apenas a sua origem: a implicação, mais clara na resposta do Jorge, é também uma certo apego a essa qualquer coisa, ou mesmo orgulho. Um corintiano roxo poderia orgulhar-se de dizer, se usasse a expressão, que era um corintiano de gema (por exemplo, se o pai o tivesse inscrito como sócio do clube aos dois meses de idade).

Comment: Jacinto, um ex-presidente realmente disse, em discurso para o povão, que "tenho aquilo roxo".  Ele quis referir-se à bolsa escrotal e testículos com o significado "sou muito macho!"

Comment: Eu sabia o que _aquilo_ era. Foi por isso que na minha imaginação descontrolada pensei, tal como o Bruno sugeriu, mas estando a pensar um coisa diferente da dele, que *português roxo* pudesse significar no Brasil o mesmo que  *português de gema* em Portugal: seria apenas um caso de os portugueses remontarem a sua origem à mãe, e os brasileiros ao pai.

Comment: @BrunoLopes , "o que é um português roxo?": http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1194/o-que-%C3%A9-um-portugu%C3%AAs-roxo

Answer (score 5):

**Aqui nascido e aqui criado.**

O significado de "gema" em "tuga **de** gema" é o mesmo significado de "gema" em "carioca **da** gema".  Dizer que é um **"tuga de gema"** é dizer-se um "português legítimo", filho de portugueses, nascido e criado em Portugal. Aqui no Rio de Janeiro a expressão **"carioca da gema"** é muito comum. **"Carioca"**, para aqueles que desconhecem, é o adjetivo que se usa para aqueles que nascem na cidade do Rio de Janeiro, mas não no estado. Acredito que não seja tão comum essa expressão "da gema" em outros estados brasileiros. Haja vista, quando em viagem pelo Brasil, por duas vezes me perguntaram o que significava exatamente ser "carioca da gema".  Pensavam que "a gema" fosse a região mais central da cidade. Mas não, ser **carioca da gema**, assim como ser tuga de gema, significa ser **"legítimo"** **,** **"aqui nascido"** e **"aqui criado"**.

Comment: +1 Gostei do **"legítimo"** **,** **aqui nascido** e **aqui criado**".