# O que é um português "roxo"?

Tags: significado, português-brasileiro, expressões

Ao ser discutido [numa pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/o-que-seria-um-tuga-de-gema) o que é um português "de gema", surgiu a possibilidade de significar um português "roxo":

> Aqui pelo Portuguese SE e pelo chat percebi que os portugueses têm o costume de se chamarem de "tuga de gema".
>
> Pesquisei sobre "tuga" e descobri que é a abreviação de "portuga", mas por que "de gema"? Seria equivalente a ser um "português roxo"?

Parece que não são a mesma coisa... mas então, **o que é ser um português "roxo"**?

Comment: Só pra confirmar: em Portugal, "roxo" não é usado nesse sentido?

Comment: Ainda não é. Vou começar a usar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No Brasil quando se diz que alguém é "*{alguma coisa}* roxo" significa que essa pessoa é *{alguma coisa}* com uma convicção, uma paixão que beira o fanatismo, mas sem o sentido pejorativo que a palavra fanático tem. Por exemplo, um flamenguista roxo é um torcedor do Flamengo que é apaixonado, não perde um jogo, fica eufórico quando o time vence e totalmente arrasado quando perde.

Pelo que eu vi nas respostas à outra pergunta, "de gema" não tem esse sentido de apaixonado que "roxo" tem.

Comment: Ouço mais frequentemente "ele é um flamenguista doente" i.e., "fanático".

Answer (score 11):

Reforçando o que a Raquel [disse](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/1197/47), "roxo" no Brasil, além de ser o nome de uma [cor](http://mlb-s2-p.mlstatic.com/papel-adesivo-vinil-roxo-fosco-45-cm-x-10-metros-18507-MLB20157239009_092014-F.jpg), também é usado para denotar que alguém tem uma [grande fervorosidade por algo](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno/portugues/definicao/roxo%20_1039376.html).

Não existe exclusivamente o termo "português roxo", mas sim o substantivo "português", que pode ser qualquer outro substantivo relacionado a uma pessoa, com o adjetivo "roxo".

Um português roxo seria um português que tem orgulho de ser português, que gosta de mostrar a todos que é português, ama fazer tudo que um português faz, defende a nacionalidade e língua, etc. Ou seja, é um português fervoroso, em contraste com um português que seja indiferente quanto a (ou que não goste de) tudo isso.

Comment: Como Collor dizia "Eu tenho aquilo roxo". Pode significar que tem coragem ou determinação para fazer algo.

Answer (score 6):

**roxo** tem mais a ver com fanatismo, como futebol.

**da gema** tem mais a ver com origem, como nacionalidade.

*"Fulano é corintiano roxo"* significa que fulano tem muito amor pelo time. Já *"João é um português da gema"* significa que ele é português mesmo, provavelmente nasceu em Portugal, conhece as tradições e se comporta como um legítimo português.

edit:
Considerando o Português-BR e o meio que estou envolvido (Mineirês).

Comment: Ficaria mal dizer *João é português roxo*? Para dizer, por exemplo, que ele é muito patriótico. Imagino então que sejas Carioca, não?

Comment: Esses termos dependem muito do meio social que estamos inseridos, e não posso dar certeza que ninguém usaria dessa forma. Mas, ao meu ver, português roxo soa estranho. Não sei se tem outro uso de "roxo" sem ser relacionado com time de futebol...

Comment: Afinal a expressão "de gema" é mais comum no Brasil do algumas pessoas pensam. Isto tudo começou porque aqui um membro brasileiro da comunidade pensou que "de gema" fosse um lusitanismo e [fez esta pergunta](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/o-que-seria-um-tuga-de-gema)

Comment: @Jacinto Nunca ouvi "de gema" no Brasil, mas "**da** gema" é sim usado, com o mesmo sentido. O sentido de "roxo" é muito próximo, mas como disse o Fabrício tem casos que combinam melhor com um ou outro adjetivo. Para lugar de origem, "da gema" é comum, e "roxo" soa mesmo estranho.

Comment: Seja bem aparecido! De/da é mais uma daquelas diferençazinhas, mas ao que parece a expressão não é conhecida em [certas regiões do Brasile chegou-se a pensar que _roxo_ pudesse significar o mesmo que _da gema_](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1183/o-que-seria-um-tuga-de-gema?lq=1),  mas já está tudo esclarecido.

Comment: Ficar roxo é morrer